# Getting String Data from a Handler to change Battery Images

Tags: android

I Have a problem with my project. I am stuck by because I cant take out my string from Handler because the Handler wipes out the data. I am new at this and I get the Handler code from https://gist.github.com/ashebby/db63b0db7489d604841a. My problem is my Android Apps is getting a percentage data about my Device Battery, but because the handler keeps wiping the string, it can't change my ImageResource. Is there a way to store the string? and will be updated if my handler got new string but not erased by it?

Here's my code:

```
 bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
            recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~
            int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("~");                    // determine the end-of-line
            if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                myLabel3.setText("Data Received = " + dataInPrint);

                if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '#')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                {
                    String readBat = recDataString.substring(1, 3);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                    //myLabel2.setText(" Tegangan Batre = " + sensor0 + "V");   //update the textviews with sensor values
                    myLabel2.setText(bacaBat);
                    //String bacaPercentage = bacaBat.substring(2,3);

                    if (readBat == "50"){
                        batt.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_50);
                    } else
                    if (readBat == "25"){
                        batt.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_25);
                    } else
                    if (readBat == "0"){
                        batt.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_0);
                    } else
                    if (readBat == "100"){
                        batt.setImageResource(R.drawable.bath_100);
                    }
                }

                if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '*')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                {
                    String bacaPD = recDataString.substring(1, 10);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5
                    //myLabel.setText(" Hasil Bacaan Photodiode = " + sensor1 + "V");
                    myLabel.setText(bacaPD);
                }

                recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                // strIncom =" ";
                dataInPrint = " ";
            }
        }
    }
};
```